# What is equivalent query in yii2

Tags: yii2

As search filtering is not working when use findbysql in yii2 searchmodel, so I want to write an equivalent query of "`SELECT * FROM challan WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM challan GROUP BY sid)`" in Yii2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer after spending many hours and here it is

```
Challan::find()->Where(['challan.id' => Challan::find()->select(['MAX(id)'])->groupBy('sid')]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->andWhere(new Expression('id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM challan GROUP BY sid)'));
```

Comment: I hv tried but the error occurred is "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `challan` LEFT JOIN `student` ON `challan`.`sid` = `student`.`sid` LEFT JOIN `campus` ON `challan`.`campus_id` = `campus`.`id` LEFT JOIN `classes` ON `challan`.`class_id` = `classes`.`id` WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM challan GROUP BY sid)"

Comment: try this: $query->andWhere(new Expression('id IN (SELECT MAX(ch.id) FROM challan as ch GROUP BY sid)'));